# Как удалить строки содержащие NaN в одном столбце и заданное значение в другом?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'фрукт': ['груша','арбуз','банан','груша', 'груша', 'вишня', 'груша', 'вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша', 'груша'],
'страна': ['сша', 'россия', 'россия', np.nan, np.nan,'россия', 'франция', 'португалия', 'россия', np.nan, np.nan],
'id': ['01','01','011', '011', '011', '011', '6', '6', '5', '5', '5'],
'месяц': ['июнь','январь','январь', 'январь', 'май', 'январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'сентябрь', 'январь']        
}
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','страна', 'id', 'месяц'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно удалить строки, которые одновременно не содержат `страну` и `месяц` не `январь`

Как можно это сделать?

Ожидаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @MaxU Потому что условие через союз "и" указано :)

Comment: тогда почему удалена строка с индексом 10 ??

Comment: @MaxU Потому что надо удалить те строки, которые не имеют страны и содержат месяц отличный от "Январь". Стррока с индексом 10 не удалена, она стала строкой с индексом 8

Comment: союз "и" - не выполняется т.к. `страна == NaN и месяц == январь`, т.е. условие ` месяц != январь` не выполняется

Comment: @MaxU Строка с индексом 10 не удалена, она стала строкой с индексом 8. Не совсем понял ваше послднее сообщение. Хотите, чтобы я по-другому сформулировал условеи?

Comment: вот так делать не нужно - это запутывает! Можете представить результат с исходными индексами, чтобы было понятно что удаляется, а что нет?

Comment: @MaxU изменил скрин результата

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = df.drop(df.query("страна != страна and месяц != 'январь'").index)
```

или:

```
res = df.query("страна == страна or месяц == 'январь'")
```

результат:

```
In [62]: res
Out[62]:
      фрукт      страна   id   месяц
0     груша         сша   01    июнь
1     арбуз      россия   01  январь
2     банан      россия  011  январь
3     груша         NaN  011  январь
5     вишня      россия  011  январь
6     груша     франция    6  январь
7     вишня  португалия    6  январь
8   абрикос      россия    5  январь
10    груша         NaN    5  январь
```

PS для фильтрации `NaN` можно использовать тот факт, что `NaN != NaN` (т.е. `NaN` не равен самому себе):

```
In [65]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[65]: False
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот так можно выбрать то, что оставить (инвертированы оба условия и `и` превратилось в `или`):

```
dates.loc[~dates.страна.isna() | (dates.месяц == 'январь')]
```